# TypeError: __jquery2.default.ajax is not a function when I used $ as jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, express, ecmascript-6

I am performing a `GET` request to my `Express` server. When I do so, my server is supposed to perform an AJAX request to the `Instagram` API. However, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: _jquery2.default.ajax is not a function
    at /Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/server/server.js:53:7
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at goNext (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/middleware.js:194:41)
    at processRequest (/Users/bli1/Development/projects/bradford/node_modules/webpack-dev-middleware/middleware.js:236:12)
```

Here is the snippet of my server code:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

app.get("/instagram", (req, res) => {
    const instagramEndpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=";
    const limit = 16;
    const user = "usertest";
    const keys = require('./keys.json');
    const accessToken = keys.instagram.accessToken;
    console.log('Hit Instagram API');
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: instagramEndpoint + accessToken[user],
        dataType: 'json',
        success: payload => {
            console.log(payload);
            return payload;
        },
        error: payload => {
            console.log(payload);

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is jquery loaded by the time you are calling it?

Comment: @Bindrid it should be? It's imported on top but maybe asynchronous nature of everything is causing some race conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I could manage to make jquery work in my express route is by using jsdom to simulate a DOM environment.

```
app.get('/silos', (request, response) => {
  require('jsdom').env('', (err, window) => {
    const $ = require('jquery')(window);
    $.get('http://demo2632149.mockable.io/silos')
      .then((successResponse) => {
        response.send(successResponse);
      });
  });
});
```

Otherwise, if all you're trying to do is make a REST call, I highly recommend using [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios).

```
import axios from 'axios';

app.get('/silos', (request, response) => {
  axios.get('http://demo2632149.mockable.io/silos')
    .then((successResponse) => {
      response.send(successResponse.data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not used node.js so guessing a little here but try this...

```
import $ from 'jquery';          

 $(document).ready( function () {

                app.get("/instagram", (req, res) => {
                    const instagramEndpoint = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=";
                    const limit = 16;
                    const user = "usertest";
                    const keys = require('./keys.json');
                    const accessToken = keys.instagram.accessToken;
                    console.log('Hit Instagram API');
                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'GET',
                        url: instagramEndpoint + accessToken[user],
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: payload => {
                            console.log(payload);
                            return payload;
                        },
                        error: payload => {
                            console.log(payload);

                        }
                    });
                });

            });
```