# Ajax call returns undefined

Tags: ajax, api, reactjs

I am trying to make an API call and the following errors with Ajax not being a function:

```
import $ from 'jquery';

const apiCall = function () {
  var url = 'https://images.nasa.gov/#/search-results';

  var request = {
    q: 'sun',
    media_type: 'image'
  };

  var result = $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: request,
    type: 'GET'
  })
  .done(function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(result));
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('failed');
  })
}

module.exports = apiCall;
```

I am importing the above in another module and calling it on a button click in the react's render() function like:

```
import apiCall from './../api/apiCall';

class Gallery extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <section id="gallery" className="g-site-container gallery">
        <div className="grid grid--full">
          <div className="gallery__intro">
                <Button extraClass=""
                  type="button"
                  handleButtonClick={apiCall} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

module.exports = Gallery;
```

Any thoughts with what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what are the errors?  Can't solve a problem if you don't tell us what it is.

Comment: Hi @gravityplanx, told you in the first line, i am getting `_jquery2.default.ajax is not a function` and **undefined** from `console.log($.ajax)`

Comment: try using $.ajax inside  `$(document).ready( function () {` ?

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva, I've tried that but with no luck unfortunately.. I am getting the same error.

Comment: Someone has reported a similar error here. did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092662/typeerror-jquery2-default-ajax-is-not-a-function-when-i-used-as-jquery

Comment: Try using the shorthand version: `$.get('/endpoint/goes/here?number=1', function(res) { //do code stuff here}.bind(this));`

Comment: what do you get from `console.log($)`?

Comment: Hi @Sag1v, I have jquery on the page, I've checked.

Comment: @Manu can you update the question with correct error, which you have added in comment 2

Comment: Hi @SrikanthJeeva, I've checked your link above which was pointing to another similar issue. I wanted to stay away from another dependency but I decided to give it ago and seems like axios has solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, this type of issue is most often because your transpilation is not working as you might expect - or you are transpiling your code while also using `jquery` (or any other lib) by including it with a CDN link. If this is the case, here's some info that might help you sort it out:

First, check that your transpiler is actually pulling `jquery` in. Just having it on the page won't necessarily allow this code to work - because when your transpiler operates on:

```
import $ from 'jquery'
```

It's going to expect to first load the `jquery` package from `node_modules` and then create an internal name for it, such as `$_1` which will be used inside your bundle. If you intend to include `jquery` on the page via CDN, rather than bundling it in this fashion, you need to mark it as `external` in your `webpack` or `rollup` config. If using `webpack`, it would look something like:

```
{
  entry: '/path/to/your/application.js',
  externals: {
    'jquery': '$',
  }
}
```

This essentially tells webpack, "when I import from `'jquery'`, don't look in `node_modules` - instead, just assume `jquery` already exists on the page as `window.$`. Now, `webpack` won't attempt to include and bundle all of the `jquery` lib - and instead of creating `$_1` it will actually honor what `$` is.

If you *do* intend to load and bundle `jquery` as part of your build (not recommended, due to the incredible size-bloat it will entail) - I suggest ensuring that it's installed in `node_modules`. You can do this with:

```
npm install -S jquery
```

or, if you're using `yarn`:

```
yarn add jquery
```

Now, your `import` statement should load the lib correctly when you re-transpile.

Answer (score 1):

First, ensure you're not using [**jquery-lite**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-lite) as it excludes `ajax` features.

Btw, it's not recommended to use both `exports.module` together with ES6's `import / export`. Try to just use one of them. Not pretty sure, but it may cause some `module` troubles that hard to understand.

Additionally, based on [**$.ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) official document, you have to process data in the callback

```
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: request,
    type: 'GET'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    // Process data provided from callback function
    alert(data);
  })
  .fail(function() {
    alert('failed');
  })
```

Personally I do prefer [**isomorphic-fetch**](https://github.com/matthew-andrews/isomorphic-fetch) to make ajax call in `React` application.

Comment: the problem is `_jquery2.default.ajax is not a function` and `undefined` from `console.log($.ajax)`

Comment: @SrikanthJeeva Updated the anwser